# Rails: Fill in form on invalid data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails form, and the label and input-box for each field are under a `div class="field"`. When the user enters invalid data, rails changes the class to `div class="field_with_errors"` for me. My question is, when this happens, how do I populate the input-box with some predefined text?

I realize this is possible with javascript, but I'm clueless on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this on the server side by using `errors[:attribute]`. You can find more info on the [ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations_overview-errors).

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a default for your columns when creating the table, these will be used to pre-populate the forms.

Here's an example of a migration which specified defaults, that are then used by the form:

```
class CreateDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :devices do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :msgs_checked, :default => true
      t.string :app_version, :default => 'Not Known'
      t.boolean :active, :default => true

      t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Comment: This specifies a default for the form in any situation. I want to specify a default for the column only after they have been submitted atleast once with an error (validation fail). (i.e I need some way to check that a validation failed, or that the class of the form changed and then fill it in with some text)